MudNumericField not Immediate when operated
Currently, I have created a Blazor Server App .Net 8.0 project using MudBlazor, in the .razor page I have created a MudNumericField
@using System.Globalization

<MudNumericField Immediate="true" Format="#,##0" Culture="@_vn" @bind-Value="_value" />

@code {
    public CultureInfo _vn = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
    public decimal? _value { get; set; }
}

I have assigned Immediate="true" to MudNumericField but when entering it still does not insert the thousand separator, only inserts the thousand separator when clicking outside the input box.
If anyone has encountered the same situation as me and knows how to fix it, please help me. Thank you everyone.

It's working as expected in try.mudblazor environment. MudBlazor Snippet.
You can also try using MudTextField it works using that component as well.
<MudNumericField Immediate="true" Format="#,###" Culture="@_vn" @bind-Value="_numericValue" Label="NumericField"/>

<MudTextField Format="#,###" Culture="@_vn" Label="Text Field Format" @bind-Value="_textValue"  Variant="@Variant.Text" Immediate="true" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentText="₫" AdornmentColor="Color.Warning"/>


@code {
    private CultureInfo _vn = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
    private decimal? _numericValue { get; set; }
    private decimal? _textValue {get;set;}
}


I tried it on the try.mudblazor environment, it works fine, but when I put it into the Blazor Server App .Net 8.0 project, it doesn't work. I tried creating a new project many times but it didn't work. It only works on the Blazor WebAssembly App environment, even though I tried the latest version of MudBlazor, it still didn't work.

Did you create a new project using MudBlazor Templates

https://www.mediafire.com/file/3on8bwpjn186z7k/BlazorServerApp.rar/file Here is my example

Try adding TextUpdateSuppression="false" to the MudNumericField.

Thank you very much, I added the "TextUpdateSuppression="false" and it worked. God bless you and your family.
